# Can I capture the IP address of every user that logs into my website

Tags: ip, ip-address

I have been asked to get details of every user that logs into our website. Is it possible to capture the IP address of every user that logs into our website from which I can gather details using IP lookup software.

Comment: There are APIs in every language even in scripting language like JavaScript to get the IP address even the host computer name...In what language you are seeking an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's already captured. Check out the web logs for whatever your webserver is.

In IIS, it's likely in `C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles`. Apache will normally be in `/var/log`.

You can tweak the specifics of what it captures, but by default IP address is always included.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are explicitly required to store the ip:s yourself, I recommend using [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/), which will sort out unique/returning visitors, geographical locations and so on.